What is the Korean symbol for the Near-open front unrounded vowel (The "AH" in "apple")?
What is the hangul symbol for the Near-open front unrounded vowel?
Alternatively worded, how do we write the "ah" sound in 한글?
In the English language we have the "AH" sound in "apple" or the "AH" sound in "candle".

The best approximation is probably ㅐ ae /ɛ/, though most speakers no longer differentiate it from ㅔ e /e/, pronouncing both as [e̞].
It may be used in loanwords from English such as 개그 (gaegeu) ‘gag’ or 냅킨 (naepkin) ‘napkin’.
